# Frechet derivative of trace of matrix expression

Tags: frechet-derivative

I am new to the concept of Frechet Derivatives. I have encountered a problem where I am supposed to find the Frechet derivative of $\operatorname{trace}(XAX+AXA^T)$ where my $X,A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ and $X=X^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(X) = {\rm tr}(XAX+AXA^T)$. Since ${\rm tr}$ is a linear functional, the total derivative of ${\rm tr}$ is ${\rm tr}$ itself, so the product rule gives $$Df(X)(H) = {\rm tr}(HAX+XAH+AHA^T).$$

Comment: It should be noted that, using the cyclic property of the trace, this can be rewritten as 
$$
Df(X)(H) = \operatorname{tr}[(AX + XA + A^TA)H],
$$
which is useful if we want to write this derivative [in another form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Although to be honest, I have always found the notation $\partial/\partial X$ very weird if $X$ is a matrix.

Comment: It's weird, but it's useful for many applications (e.g. finding a "gradient" of your function for some optimization).

Comment: Oh. When I need a gradient I always try to rearrange my result in the form $({\rm foo})^TH$, so gradient equals "foo", but it makes sense that there should be a smarter way to do this.

Comment: Well that's certainly the way to do it that way if you're working from scratch (at least I think so). However, the "Matrix Cookbook" type table of $\partial / \partial X$ derivatives essentially gives you the gradient for common (scalar valued) functions on matrices.